# problem with justify-content:center; in flexbox

Tags: html, css

I want to know why the video and the second container don't center in the middle of the page when I gave it the `justify-content` as you see in the third and fourth container the boxes align in the middle.

I tried everything, from margin to float to grid, but it's not working.
Again sorry for the question but I'm a beginner in this game.

```css
/* body and root stuff */
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0.813rem;
  font-family: "Assistant", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: white;
}
img {
  width: 20%;
}
header {
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(255, 123, 0);
  color: white;
  padding: 2em auto;
}
/* body and root stuff end */
/* header stuff */
.main-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-container-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
.logo-container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-right: 8em;
  align-self: center;
}
#header-img {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 0.75em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
nav,
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.current-page {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}
a:hover {
  color: orange;
  border-bottom: none;
}

@media (min-width: 675px) {
  .main-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 900px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .main-container-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .logo-container {
    width: 15%;
    height: 15%;
    align-self: center;
  }
  #header-img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0.75em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0.4em;
  }
  nav,
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  li {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 2em;
    align-self: center;
  }
  .current-page {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;

    color: white;
    font-weight: 650;
  }
  a:hover {
    color: orange;
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}

/* header stuff ends */ /* main stuff */
main {
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  padding: 2em auto;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.video-container {
  max-width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
#video {
  align-self: center;
}
hr {
  margin: 2rem 10%;
  background: rgb(255, 123, 0);
}

.products-title {
  background: rgb(255, 123, 0);
  color: white;
  max-width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.h2-product-title {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.p-product-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .products-title {
    background: rgb(255, 123, 0);
    color: white;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
.products {
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bindings-picture {
  width: 20em;
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin-right: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="img/Union-U-Orange.png" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Assistant:wght@200;300;400;600;700;800&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>UNION BINDINGS CO.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="header" class="stick-header">
      <div class="main-container main-container-flex">
        <div class="logo-container">
          <img
            id="header-img"
            src="/img/b89780745f1e81adc10408d92c7c6dda.jpg"
            alt="union logo"
          />
        </div>
        <nav id="nav-bar">
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-link">
              <a href="" target="_blank" class="current-page">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="" target="_blank">Product</a></li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="" target="_blank">Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="video-container">
        <iframe
          id="video"
          width="560"
          height="315"
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CQtZRHnbPks"
          frameborder="0"
          allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="products-title">
        <h2 class="h2-product-title">OUR BINDINGS</h2>
        <p class="p-product-title">
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi
          doloremque dicta repellendus, iste unde voluptas.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="products">
        <div class="bindings">
          <img
            class="bindings-picture"
            src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61R7kSDMCVL._AC_SL1500_.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
          <p class="binding-name">
            Union Force
          </p>
          <a href="https://www.google.com"><button>MORE INFO</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="bindings">
          <img
            class="bindings-picture"
            src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61R7kSDMCVL._AC_SL1500_.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
          <p class="binding-name">
            Union Force
          </p>
          <a href="https://www.google.com"><button>MORE INFO</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="bindings">
          <img
            class="bindings-picture"
            src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61R7kSDMCVL._AC_SL1500_.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
          <p class="binding-name">
            Union Force
          </p>
          <a href="https://www.google.com"><button>MORE INFO</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="bindings">
          <img
            class="bindings-picture"
            src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61R7kSDMCVL._AC_SL1500_.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
          <p class="binding-name">
            Union Force
          </p>
          <a href="https://www.google.com"><button>MORE INFO</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="more-products-container">
        <div class="products"></div>
        <div class="products"></div>
        <div class="products"></div>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="newsletter">
        <form action=" https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit)" id="form">
          <h3>SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h3>
          <input type="name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" />
          <input
            class="email-holder"
            type="email"
            id="email"
            placeholder="email"
          />
          <input id="submit" type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS for the `main` identifier, you have `flex-direction: column;` so you need `align-items: center;`, not `justify-content: center;`. Also, I love [this resource](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on Flexbox.

`align-items` is used for the "cross axis" (if you're adding elements in the column flex direction, the cross axis is the horizontal, and you want your stuff centered horizontally; `justify-contents` follows the direction axis so it would be trying to center things vertically).

Here's the updated chunk of code in question:

```
/* ... other styles were above ... */
main {
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  padding: 2em auto;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center; /* don't need this */
  align-items: center;
}
/* ... there's more stuff below ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

Your flex direction is `column` - so you need to use `align-items: center` instead.

`justify-content: center` centers elements in the direction of the flex-flow. `align-items` aligns flex children on the cross axis of the direction (in this case column).

If your flex-direction was `row` - `align-items: center` would vertically center the flex children, since it's the cross axis of the main flex direction.

```css
/* body and root stuff */
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0.813rem;
  font-family: "Assistant", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: white;
}
img {
  width: 20%;
}
header {
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(255, 123, 0);
  color: white;
  padding: 2em auto;
}
/* body and root stuff end */
/* header stuff */
.main-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-container-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
.logo-container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-right: 8em;
  align-self: center;
}
#header-img {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 0.75em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
nav,
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.current-page {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}
a:hover {
  color: orange;
  border-bottom: none;
}

@media (min-width: 675px) {
  .main-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 900px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .main-container-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .logo-container {
    width: 15%;
    height: 15%;
    align-self: center;
  }
  #header-img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0.75em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0.4em;
  }
  nav,
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  li {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 2em;
    align-self: center;
  }
  .current-page {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;

    color: white;
    font-weight: 650;
  }
  a:hover {
    color: orange;
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}

/* header stuff ends */ /* main stuff */
main {
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  padding: 2em auto;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.video-container {
  max-width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
#video {
  align-self: center;
}
hr {
  margin: 2rem 10%;
  background: rgb(255, 123, 0);
}

.products-title {
  background: rgb(255, 123, 0);
  color: white;
  max-width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.h2-product-title {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.p-product-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .products-title {
    background: rgb(255, 123, 0);
    color: white;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
.products {
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bindings-picture {
  width: 20em;
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin-right: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="img/Union-U-Orange.png" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Assistant:wght@200;300;400;600;700;800&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>UNION BINDINGS CO.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="header" class="stick-header">
      <div class="main-container main-container-flex">
        <div class="logo-container">
          <img
            id="header-img"
            src="/img/b89780745f1e81adc10408d92c7c6dda.jpg"
            alt="union logo"
          />
        </div>
        <nav id="nav-bar">
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-link">
              <a href="" target="_blank" class="current-page">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="" target="_blank">Product</a></li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="" target="_blank">Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="video-container">
        <iframe
          id="video"
          width="560"
          height="315"
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CQtZRHnbPks"
          frameborder="0"
          allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="products-title">
        <h2 class="h2-product-title">OUR BINDINGS</h2>
        <p class="p-product-title">
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi
          doloremque dicta repellendus, iste unde voluptas.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="products">
        <div class="bindings">
          <img
            class="bindings-picture"
            src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61R7kSDMCVL._AC_SL1500_.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
          <p class="binding-name">
            Union Force
          </p>
          <a href="https://www.google.com"><button>MORE INFO</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="bindings">
          <img
            class="bindings-picture"
            src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61R7kSDMCVL._AC_SL1500_.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
          <p class="binding-name">
            Union Force
          </p>
          <a href="https://www.google.com"><button>MORE INFO</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="bindings">
          <img
            class="bindings-picture"
            src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61R7kSDMCVL._AC_SL1500_.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
          <p class="binding-name">
            Union Force
          </p>
          <a href="https://www.google.com"><button>MORE INFO</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="bindings">
          <img
            class="bindings-picture"
            src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61R7kSDMCVL._AC_SL1500_.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
          <p class="binding-name">
            Union Force
          </p>
          <a href="https://www.google.com"><button>MORE INFO</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="more-products-container">
        <div class="products"></div>
        <div class="products"></div>
        <div class="products"></div>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="newsletter">
        <form action=" https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit)" id="form">
          <h3>SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h3>
          <input type="name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" />
          <input
            class="email-holder"
            type="email"
            id="email"
            placeholder="email"
          />
          <input id="submit" type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`justify-content:center` is working. It's just centering it to the width of the container that's set to 900px

```
.video-container {
   //this width
   max-width: 900px;
   display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Change width to 100% and it will work fine

Comment: I'm pretty sure this "works" (it "looks right") but it wasn't what was intended by the asker.